# Can metaheuristics be used to optimize a non-convex function $f(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) = \frac{y_1}{x_1} + \frac{y_2}{x_2}$?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I want to use genetic algorithm for minimizing the above function where $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to find a local/approximate solutions using metaheuristics such as genetic algorithms? Or what are the methods can we use to optimize non-convex optimization functions provided approximate(not global minimum/maximum) solutions are acceptable?

Comment: What are the restrictions on the variables?

Comment: $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$